# How to show vertical pane in Outlook add-ins in Outlook Web App (OWA), Outlook 2016 Mac & Windows

Tags: office-addins, office-js, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an outlook add-in targeting OWA, Outlook 2016 for Mac & Windows.  My requirement is to show the **add-in vertically on right side** while reading and composing mail. For compose it is by default showing as desired but for reading it is showing horizontally which I want to show vertically. In short I like to show my add-in **exactly same as Evernote add-in** is showing.

Your help will be much appreciated. Following screen-shot of Evernote in OWA is what I want to show including icon location (enclosed in red).

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Any success on achieving it?

Comment: I'm trying to implement same kind of thing. Are you able to achieve it ?

Comment: @alekkowalczyk  It is happening now as mentioned by AnOberoi below.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar  It is happening now as mentioned by AnOberoi below.

Comment: @PremchandraSingh can you please provide any link where you have seen this ?\

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Actually we are actively developing add-in and our add-in is visible vertically now which was visible horizontally day before. We don't have any link.

Comment: @PremchandraSingh have you implemented commands to display the button the way you have mentioned in the image? or it works without commands?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar I did not implement but with the update from Microsoft, my add-in icon is showing over there. Please read the answer below from AnOberoi

Answer (score 3):

I make such vertical add-in using YEOMAN Office Generator. for reference use this link.
[GitHub link for yeoman-office-generator.](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office) 
And make changes in your manifest.xml file is as belows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns=
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:type="MailApp">

  <Id>7856b76d-42c2-4b40-87df-c4bfb706246f</Id>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-us</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Alore MailTracker"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Send and Track your emails.">
    <Override Locale="fr-fr" Value="Send and track your emails with Alore Emailtracker."/>
  </Description>
  <!-- Change the following line to specify    -->
  <!-- the web serverthat hosts the icon file. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="Mailbox" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <!-- Change the following line to specify     -->
        <!-- the web server that hosts the HTML file. -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" />
        <RequestedHeight>216</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <!-- Change the following line to specify     -->
        <!-- the web server that hosts the HTML file. -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" />
        <RequestedHeight>216</RequestedHeight>
      </TabletSettings>
    </Form>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <!-- Change the following line to specify     -->
        <!-- the web server that hosts the HTML file. -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" />
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <!-- Change the following line to specify     -->
        <!-- the web server that hosts the HTML file. -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" />
      </TabletSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or"> 
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
      <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
      </Rule>
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" 
        PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" RegExName="VideoURL" 
        RegExValue="https://localhost:3000/resource.html" />
    </Rule>
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" /> 
    </Rule> 
  </Rule>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add-in commands will be rolling out soon to all users and all add-ins for Outlook Web and we expect it to be at a 100% in the month of Dec. Once its rolled out you'll be able to have buttons in OWA that launch task pane, as you see in the screenshot. For Outlook desktop for Windows, this feature is already available however for Outlook for MAC too we expect this to be out in December!

Comment: Thanks, today we found that buttons are showing at the upper panel as shown in my screenshot. Yet to check on Mac. If it is happening on Mac then it will be so great. Thanks in advance

Comment: one more question. I have posted a question on this link please have a look if you got a chance. The question is regarding manipulation email body while sending it. Thanks in advance

Comment: So office.js Add-In support for Outlook for Mac on desktop should be available on December? I'm on the fast insider program and still not seeing it.

Comment: I missed providing the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018216/how-to-hook-event-on-sending-mail-in-office-add-in-owa-windows-outlook-2016) to my above comment.

Comment: @alek: The insider fast for MAC was just deployed yesterday :), might have missed you by hours. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/outlookformac/2016/12/07/add-ins-for-outlook-2016-for-mac-now-in-insider-fast/