# Vertical panel add-in in Outlook online

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, outlook-addin, office365api

I want to develop my own Outlook add-in. As I can see in my outlook.com account, there is a possibility to show add-in in vertical panel in Outlook online, not in horizontal inlined panel inside letter. For example, add-ins for Wunderlist and Evernote.
 What should I do to run my add-in in vertical panel in Outlook online (not in Outlook Desktop for Windows)? I saw in the MS documentation, that vertical pane add-in is only allowed in compose mode, but as I can see in reality, it is not true: 
[evernote add-in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8WqS.png) 
[wunderlist add-in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNAKa.png)

Also, in my old account on some exchange server, add-in for Wunderlist is shown as horizontal pane, not vertical for some reason.

So, my questions are:
1) Is outlook vertical pane add-ins available only for some partners of Microsoft? And when it will be available to everyone else?
2) How can I create vertical pane add-in in Outlook online?

Comment: Similar question has been posted here without answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593204/how-to-show-vertical-pane-in-outlook-add-ins-in-outlook-web-app-owa-outlook-2

Comment: @BenoitPatra that question doesn't have proper tags, so guys from MS will never look at it.

Comment: @YuliiLyubeznkov Are you able to achieve this ?

Comment: Refer this answer for this[ link for yeoman-office-generator.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43490131/7326231)