# How to add Custom Mail Action that open add-in Task Pane in OWA (Email Read Mode)

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

I would like to implement custom Mail Action that will open Task Pane. I know that it's possible as some add-ins have it. Below is an example of Custom Mail Action and Task Pane.

[image]

I know how to add horizontal task pane to the add-in, but I need to add it vertical to the right as in the screenshot.

There are a few similar questions on StackOverflow but they all tell it's impossible to implement. As you can see on the image some add-ins like Evernote, Wunderlist has this functionality.

Comment: This question as already been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593204/how-to-show-vertical-pane-in-outlook-add-ins-in-outlook-web-app-owa-outlook-2 without any answer. Hope this one will receive one.

Comment: Yes, the playing field should be the same for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just announced at Ignite conference that add-in commands will be rolling out to all users and all add-ins for Outlook web (Outlook.com, Office 365 and OWA on Exchange 2016 on-prem) over the next 2 months. With that feature, you'll be able to have buttons in OWA that launch task pane, as you see in the screenshot.

Comment: @AnderwS is this feature is available now in outlook web app ?

Comment: no, but very soon. it'll be rolling out to 100% in the month of december

Comment: My actual mail action icon was used to show there but it is not showing now. It shows an outlook generic icon. Is there any relation with this new feature and missing icon?

Comment: It's possible the URL can no longer be retrieved. Can you check?