# How to hook event on sending mail in Office add-in (OWA, Windows Outlook 2016)

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

in (Web and Desktop), I need to observe sending email but it seems to be the API available from office.js does not seem to have any event or method for this functionality.

In fact, my requirement is to inject tracking pixels when a user clicks on Send button thereby collecting the outgoing email's conversation id.

Any suggestion?

Comment: There are no callbacks for the message sent or received in the Web Addins API... That functionality was promised when the API was first released, it is still not there...

Comment: Unfortunately Office.js API does not have "OnSend" or "OnClose" events. The user voice for Outlook developers has the request on this feature, which under review. You may up vote this feature as well by going to [link](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10964871-add-itemsend-event-so-add-in-can-cancel-email)

Answer (score 4):

It is available now. [On send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins) was implemented with lots of limitation, but at least it's there. [Outlook add-in on send code sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send) is available as well.

Answer (score 0):

Slava is correct. This is a common request and the team is considering solutions for this scenario.

Comment: What is the plan like for this feature?

Comment: "Slava is correct" - then why not comment on his answer, instead of adding a "me too" answer (even if it is from the horse's mouth)?

Answer (score 0):

"On send feature" - A lot of limitation indeed.

**Outlook desktop client:**
It's not enough to have Outlook 2019 you need at least this version 1910 (build 12130.20272).
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#supported-clients-and-platforms
You need to use API requirement sets 1.8.
To get it (for windows) you need Microsoft 365 subscription or 2019 one-time purchase (retail) according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#outlook-client-support.

**OWA works fine.**

**Exchange server**
Only Exchange Online (Latest build ) supported.
Even Exchange 2019 on-premises doesn't support it because it has max. API requirement sets 1.5
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#exchange-server-support

Bottom line: Pretty useless feature so far.