# How to identify ItemSend & BeforeAttachmentAdd events in new Office Addin for outlook

Tags: office-js

I am looking for equivalent of ItemSend & BeforeAttachmentAdd events to be implemented in my new Office outlook Addin (using HTML & JS).

From the add-in overview pages, found that ItemChanged event alone can be implemented with in the add-in and no support available for other events mentioned above.

I could be missing something. Do anyone know any solution or suggestion in identifying the equivalent events for outlook addin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer is over there ... [How to hook event on sending mail in Office add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018216/how-to-hook-event-on-sending-mail-in-office-add-in-owa-windows-outlook-2016/43982768#43982768)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hook event on sending mail in Office add-in (OWA, Windows Outlook 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018216/how-to-hook-event-on-sending-mail-in-office-add-in-owa-windows-outlook-2016)