# Outlook addin know when Send button is pressed

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin

I am beginning to have a look at Outlook addin using C# and want to know how to get notified in my addin when Send email is clicked. Is this possible in addin?

Also I want to know the email that was sent along with it's title, body, to address. I am a beginner in addin and completely confused how to achieve this.

Comment: Start by looking at the Microsoft documentation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/

Comment: This site it for answering specific questions. Try including some code and explanations of what you've tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Application.ItemSend` event for that. The item being sent will be passed as an argument to your event handler. You can check that you get a `MailItem` object (you can also have `MeetingItem` etc.) by trying to cast the object to `MailItem`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what add-in technology you're using, but as you mentioned C# then I'll assume that you're using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

It's possible to capture the send event of an [EmailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem?view=outlook-pia). You can retrieve EmailItem object and access its contents by using Inspector.

Sample code:

```
    private void Inspectors_NewInspectorEvent(Outlook.Inspector inspector)
    {
        var currentAppointment = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)currentAppointment).Send += ThisAddIn_Send;
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Send(ref bool Cancel)
    {
        //Handle send event
    }
```

If you're creating a web add-in using Office.js, send event is currently only available in Office365 OWA. Here's the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins)

**Update to include Dmitry's comment:**

You should use Application.Itemsend, you will then need to check if the being sent object is an email.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use MailItem.Send event - you will need to track each and every MailItem object that can potentially be sent. Your code above miss messages sent without being open in an inspector - a user can reply/forward an email inline. Use Application.ItemSend event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you use Web add-in technology, but here is a sample about [WEB Outlook add-in on send code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send/tree/master/outlook-add-in-on-send). The main code as below:

```
// Check if the subject should be changed. If it is already changed allow send, otherwise change it.
// <param name="subject">Subject to set.</param>
// <param name="event">MessageSend event passed from the calling function.</param>
function subjectOnSendChange(subject, event) {
    mailboxItem.subject.setAsync(
        subject,
        { asyncContext: event },
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                mailboxItem.notificationMessages.addAsync('NoSend', { type: 'errorMessage', message: 'Unable to set the subject.' });

                // Block send.
                asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false });
            }
            else {
                // Allow send.
                asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true });
            }

        });
}
```

More information please see,
[How to hook event on sending mail in Office add-in (OWA, Windows Outlook 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018216/how-to-hook-event-on-sending-mail-in-office-add-in-owa-windows-outlook-2016)

[How To: Change an Outlook e-mail message before sending using C#](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/12/outlook-change-message-before-sending/)